# Move folder contents into parent folder - Linux Commandline

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a folderA that contains folderB that contains a lot of files. I would like to get rid of folderB, but not its contents. I want those contents to be inside of folderA. How can I accomplish this on the commandline?

Answer (score 36):

```
$ cd /path/to/folderA
$ mv folderB/* .
$ rmdir folderB
```

Comment: mv folderB/* . ? what is the dot?

Comment: Watch out for dot files (files whose name begins with .) as this will not include those.  Do `mv folderB/.* .` to move them as well.  @NewLinuxUser, the dot in your question is an alias for the working directory (in this case, folderA).

Comment: This fails if `folderB/folderB` exists, so beware of using it in scripts.

Comment: This also fails if `folderB` contains an insane amount of files. You will see `bash: /bin/mv: Argument list too long` because of the use of `*`. If that's the case use `mv` in combination with `find` as stated by @amphetamachine, or with a [`for loop`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156124)

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer:

```
cd /path/to/folderA
find folderB -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec mv {} . \;
rmdir folderB
```

Code-hardy answer:

```
cd /path/to/folderA
folderB_temp="$(mktemp -d -t folderB.XXXXXX)"
mv folderB "$folderB_temp"
find "$folderB_temp/folderB" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec mv {} . \;
rmdir --parents --ignore-fail-on-non-empty "$folderB_temp/folderB"
```